# angular get image data and again append it to FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, form-data

In angular 5 I am getting the images for hotelgallery from mongodb through my service. So basically the data what I am getting is like this

```
{
  fieldname: "hotelgallery", 
  originalname: "e.jpg", 
  encoding: "7bit", 
  mimetype: "image/jpeg", 
  destination: "./public/",
  encoding : "7bit",
  filename : "1521139307413.jpg"
  mimetype : "image/jpeg"
  path : "public/1521139307413.jpg"
  size : 66474
}
{
  fieldname: "hotelgallery", 
  originalname: "e.jpg", 
  encoding: "7bit", 
  mimetype: "image/jpeg", 
  destination: "./public/",
  encoding : "7bit",
  filename : "1521139307413.jpg"
  mimetype : "image/jpeg"
  path : "public/1521139307413.jpg"
  size : 66474
}
{
  fieldname: "hotelgallery", 
  originalname: "j.jpg", 
  encoding: "7bit", 
  mimetype: "image/jpeg", 
  destination: "./public/",
  encoding : "7bit",
  filename : "1526753678390.jpg"
  mimetype : "image/jpeg"
  path : "public/1526753678390.jpg"
  size : 66470
}
{
  fieldname: "hotelgallery", 
  originalname: "k.jpg", 
  encoding: "7bit", 
  mimetype: "image/jpeg", 
  destination: "./public/",
  encoding : "7bit",
  filename : "7865456789413.jpg"
  mimetype : "image/jpeg"
  path : "public/7865456789413.jpg"
  size : 66300
}
```

Now I want to again append those data to FormData but its not working.

The code what I have done so far

```
export class HotelEditComponent implements OnInit {
   formData = new FormData();
   ngOnInit() {
    this.getOneHotel(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
   }

 getOneHotel(id) {
    this.http.get( this.apiUrl + '/api/hotel/' + id).subscribe(data => {
      this.hotel = data;
      this.appendImages(data['hotelimages']); //Here I am getting the data as mentioned here
    });
 }

 public appendImages(imagedata) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imagedata.length; i++) {
      console.log(imagedata[i]);
      this.formData.append('hotelgallery', imagedata[i], imagedata[i]['originalname']);
    }
    console.log(this.formData);
  }
 }
```

So can someone tell me how can I append the existing image data to FormData? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

**UseCase for this:**
Actually I had used formData to upload images in angular. Now in the edit page the images are showing fine. But lets say a user edits some data and upload some images or remove some images. In that case I am getting the images from the database and again trying to upload them with formdata.

I have used [this](https://aberezkin.github.io/ng2-image-upload/#/demo) module and multer for nodejs to upload images with formData.

Comment: What is `data['hotelimages']` supposed to do? There is no `hotelimages` property in the data you get from the service. What does `imagedata[i]` contain?

Comment: it should be data['path'] to display images

Comment: Actually the data is an object and from data['hotelimages'] I am getting the data for all the images.

Comment: from first sight, i think you're using wrong overload of `FormData.append()`. The one with 3 parameters is meant to be used for the case when second parameter is `Blob/File` which yours doesn't seem to be. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: @deezg then what should I do here to append the data to formdata?

Comment: i don't understand what are you trying to do actually (usecase). maybe you could describe it a bit more.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @deezg actually I had used formData to upload images in angular. Now in the edit page the images are showing fine. But lets say a user edits some data and upload some images or remove some images. In that case I am getting the images from the database and again trying to upload them with formdata.

Comment: @NagaSaiA nope no errors.

Comment: Yes, i see. `FormData.append(3 params)` for uploading images is fine because when you select image (through upload component) from disk, your second parameter is actual image `Blob`. For editing, you're actually editing image meta-data (what you get from server). In that case use just `FormData.append(parameterName, parameterStringValue)`. Only if you're uploading something again (by selecting image from disk) should you use `FormData.append(parameterName, fileFromDiskBlob, filenameString)` overload. Hope you see what i mean.

Comment: @deezg can you share code for this? So that I can understand properly.

Comment: Just omit second parameter from `FormData.append()`. So, try using `FormData.append('hotelgallery', imagedata[i]['originalname'])` and see what you're getting. I think that will give you an idea.

Comment: @deezg its adding file name to formData but not uploading images. I want it should again upload image just like add hotel page(where I am inserting the hotel data)

Comment: exactly since there is nothing to upload. can you be specific, what exactly do you expect it to upload? asking because you dont have any file raw-data to upload (which usually comes from `<input type=file />`). all you have is images metadata in that json from server. so i am not sure what are you trying to upload actually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167031/discussion-between-newuser-and-dee-zg).

Comment: Actually I am using form data to upload some files with some extra data. To upload files in node js I have used multer with mongodb. When I am doing upload those images with extra data its working fine. But there is an edit part for this page where user can edit those extra data and might add some new images or remove existing image in that case I was looking for like get all the images from db then again append them and upload them. This was my concern. If you have any other suggestion for this will be appreciable.

Comment: uploadinf involves having binary/raw-data for image. that comes from `input type=file` and thats what goes to second parameters of `FormData.append` (version with 3 params). when you delete you just delete by id, you dont need any raw image data. also, when you update you update that data you got from server which is just regular strings: name, description, etc...no raw data there so no upload.

Comment: @deezg so is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: i think it would be useful if you could show your screens (edit) so we can see what it looks like because i am not aware why update/delete is related to upload.

Answer (score 2):

> So can someone tell me how can I append the existing image data to FormData? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Actually, this approach need more add script solution. for example

**1. Get Image Blob from server**

Since you return detail object of images, not with the blob. You need have a endpoint to return as blob. (or if return as data buffer then it transform to blob you can use [BlobUtil](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util))

**2. Put Blob to append form data**

You need use blob to append in param 2 no a path, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Syntax).

> **name**
>
> The name of the field whose data is contained in value.
>
> **value**
>
> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses
> such as File).
>
> **filename Optional**
>
> The filename reported to the server
> (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter.
> The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename
> for File objects is the file's filename.

That what you need, but that is **bad practice**.

Let's say, you have 30 images to edit, then you need request blob endpoint to get those images blob to appends. But user only want to update 1 image, wasting time to request image blob, right?

For **edit** image usually we don't need append to file form (`<input type="file" />`).

Just show it as thumbnail to see what image uploaded and let file form empty.

What we do usually, thumbnail that image.

When user what to change, user put new image and replace old image with new want and update database.

if not, do nothing for image. ([YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it))

Answer (score 0):

FormData's append is silently failing here. You need to attach the 'image' as a blob. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

```
formData.append('hotelgallery', new Blob([imagedata[i]], { type: "text/xml"}), imagedata[i]['originalname']);
```

Also, just printing formData won't show anything, instead try:

```
console.log(this.formData.getAll('hotelgallery'));
```

or

```
for (var value of this.formData.values()) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But lets say a user edits some data and upload some images or remove
>   some images. In that case I am getting the images from the database
>   and again trying to upload them with formdata.

So, you can pass object to universal method and on result get `formData`. Object data even can contain nested objects.

```
 static createFormData(object: Object, form?: FormData, namespace?: string): FormData {
        const formData = form || new FormData();
        for (let property in object) {

            if (!object.hasOwnProperty(property) || object[property] === undefined) {
                continue;
            }

            const formKey = namespace ? `${namespace}[${property}]` : property;

            if (object[property] instanceof Date) {                 
                formData.append(formKey, object[property].toISOString());
            } else if (typeof object[property] === 'object' && !(object[property] instanceof File)) {
                this.createFormData(object[property], formData, formKey);
            }
            else if (typeof object[property] === 'number') {
                let numberStr = object[property].toString().replace('.', ',');
                formData.append(formKey, numberStr);
            }
            else {
                formData.append(formKey, object[property]);
            }
        }

        return formData;
    }
}
```

**In Component class:**

```
export class HotelEditComponent implements OnInit {
   formData = new FormData();
   hotel: any;
   ...
   ngOnInit() {
    this.getOneHotel(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
   }

 getOneHotel(id) {
    this.http.get( this.apiUrl + '/api/hotel/' + id).subscribe(data => {
      this.hotel = data;
    });
 }

 postToServer() {
  // or even can pass full `this.hotel` object
  // this.helperService.createFormData(this.hotel) 
  this.formData = this.helperService.createFormData(this.hotel['hotelimages']) 
  this.service.post(this.formData);

 }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to append a JSON array, since formData.append can only accept a string or blob, try the JSON.stringify() method to convert your array into a JSON string. (untested)

e.g. I think you can replace

```
this.appendImages(data['hotelimages']);
```

with

```
this.formData.append('hotelgallery', JSON.stringify(data['hotelimages']));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a design issue right now, rather then a tech problem. You are asking about posting FormData again and you want to fetch the images data again for that.

Now let's look at your current design.

1. User uploads 3 images of 4MB size each
2. On your edit page you downloads each of these images. Cost=12MB
3. On the edit page user deletes 2 images and adds 2 images. Cost=12MB
4. So final cost of updating 2 images of 8MB is 24MB. Which is a lot

Now before figuring out how to do FormData, figure out the right design for your app.

Consider the `OLX` site which allows you to post ads and later edit them. When you edit and remove a image, they call a API for removing the image

[image: Remove Image]

The ideal design in my opinion would be below

- Submit all images in your create
- For edit create a add and remove endpoint for the image

Submitting text data again on a edit form is ok, but submitting the same images data again on a edit form is never ok. Reconsider your design