# Nodejs read an external image and write as pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm

I have a html file where I have some variable like {Ticket}. In nodejs I am trying to replace that variable into an image what I have. So basically the output will be a pdf file.

So far now my code looks like this

ticket.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{Ticket}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

var html = fs.readFileSync('ticket.html', 'utf8'); //html file
var GetImage = fs.readFileSync('QRTicket.png'); //image file
var customHtml = customHtml.replace('{Ticket}', GetImage);
pdf.create(customHtml, options).toFile('QRImage.pdf', function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(res); 
});
```

But its creating a blank pdf file.
I am using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to generate pdf file. I am struggling to get this done but its not working. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable

Comment: This line: `var customHtml = customHtml.replace('{Ticket}', GetImage);` says to replace a string within its undefined self.  You'll need to start by fixing that.

Comment: How can I do that? I am just a newbie in nodejs so can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my ticket.html and now I want to search and replace multiple strings at a one place. So now my ticket.html is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src="{{Ticket}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>tyui</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the express.js looks like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const replaceOnce = require('replace-once');

const html = fs.readFileSync('ticket.html', 'utf8');
const image = 'file:///'+path.join(appRoot.path, 'file.png');

var find = ['{{Ticket}}', 'asdf', 'tyui'];
var replace = [image, 'Wills', 'Smith'];

const customHtml = replaceOnce(html, find, replace, 'gi')

pdf.create(customHtml).toFile('QRImage.pdf', (err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert the image into the page differently (using the `file://` protocol). There is actually an example on the project's GitHub page that shows you how to do this [here](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/blob/master/examples/businesscard/businesscard.html) and [here](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/blob/master/examples/serve-http/index.js).

In your case, this would translate to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><img src="{Ticket}"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');

const html = fs.readFileSync('./ticket.html', 'utf8');
const customHtml = html.replace('{Ticket}', `file://${require.resolve('./QRTicket.png')}`);

pdf.create(customHtml).toFile('QRImage.pdf', (err, res) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

**Edit:**

This example assumes the following folder structure.

```
.
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── QRTicket.png
└── ticket.html
```

Run with the command `node index.js` and it will generate the desired PDF with the image.

Comment: When I am using those codes,  getting error like this

`Error: Cannot find module './QRTicket.png'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)`

Comment: Sounds like a path issue. I've updated my answer to indicate which files should be where. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have got the answer by myself. Please check it. Let me know if still there need any correction.
Really thank you for showing the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. It would be nice if you would accept my answer if it answered your original question.

Comment: Actually I have answered by myself with all the modification. So that it would be helpful to others. FYI I have up voted your answer ;)

Comment: I have another question related to angular with bounty points. Please check and help me there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307304/angular-get-image-data-and-again-append-it-to-formdata